# Promises and Deferred are not working , finish before the timout

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var promises = J_lis.each(function(i){
    // Deferred from promises
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var setSrc = this.src;
    var setId = this.id;

    setTimeout(function() {
      // Looping thought image
      that._loadCanvasImage(setId, setSrc);
      // Resolve
      dfd.resolve();
    }, (i+1)*5000);

    // Return promise
    return dfd.promise();
}).get();

// Get when loop each is finished
  $.when.apply($, promises).then(function()
  {
    console.log("done");
  });
```

my intention is loop though image using setTimeout one by one , once is comfire done loop all the image , it move one the other function , i use the promise from js.

my function show **done** from the **console.log** before all the image are looped.

what wrong with my code ? how do i make sure all the image are looped and then pass to the then function ?

Answer (score 0):

[`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) will return `J_lis`.

You want to use [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/).

```
var promises = J_lis.map(function () {
   // return a promise here.
}).get();
```

Comment: thanks but the last loop show done before my function loadCanvasImage are finish can i make sure that done as well ?

Comment: is `_loadCanvasImage` asynchronous?